# react-native-firebase - Xcode iOS release build not working like debug build

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I've got a React Native app, that uses react-native-firebase to show notifications when the app is in the background. Since I can't seem to get Redux actions to dispatch when the app is in the background, I store the notification information (i.e. id of the resource I need to fetch when the app is in foreground) in an array called `notificationsToProcess`. I then use `AppState` to determine if the app is in foreground, if it is, then process the items in the `notificationsToProcess` array, i.e. dispatch a redux action to fetch the data from an API and update the Redux store in the app.

Now, the problem is, in XCode, when I use a build configuration of 'Debug' and push it to my iPhone, this code works fine - notifications are received and shown, the `onNotificationDisplayed` event listener fires and the `notificationsToProcess` array is updated - then when the app is in foreground, the actions are dispatched and all is well. However, when I change my schema  in Xcode to use a build configuration of 'Release', the Firebase listener no longer works. Do I need to setup something else for firebase notification listeners to work with a 'Release' build configuration in Xcode on iOS devices?

Here are the relevant snippets from my code:

```
class InitFirebaseListeners extends React.Component {
  notificationsToProcess = [];
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    this.startFirebaseListeners();
  }

  handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    const { appState } = this.state;
    if (
      appState.match(/inactive|background/)
      && nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      const { myReduxAction } = this.props;
      while (let msgId = this.notificationsToProcess.shift()) {
        myReduxAction(msgId);
      }
    }
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
  };


  startFirebaseListeners = async () => {

    this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification) => { 
      const { _data: { type, message: messageId } } = notification;
      this.notificationsToProcess.push(messageId);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had almost the same problem... the problem was that I updated React Native to the latest version, but my react-native-fireabse was v.4.x.x. With updating to v.5.x.x fixed my problem :)